# Is it necessary to apply crossorgin attribute for <script> <img> <link> tags?

Tags: html, tags

In most webapps, I saw a crossorgin attribute in some tags. I mentioned in the Title. What is the crossorgin attribute? What can it do? I found some answers to this question but i'm not understood! So i think i would re ask with this points

```
<script src ="http://filepath.js" crossorgin = "anonymous"></script>

<script src ="http://filepath.js"></script>

<script src ="http://filepath.js" crossorgin = "use-credentials"></script>
```

In the above html codes, first is using crossorgin attribute with **anonymous** property. Second one is without crossorgin and third one is with **use-credentials** property, but happing same thing. So what is the difference among this three html codes? Is there are significant difference? Is it necessary to do?